# How to execute some init after element loaded to dom with Binding.scala

Tags: scala.js, binding.scala

```
@dom 
def chart(show: Var[Boolean]) = {
  if(show.bind) {
    <canvas id="chartCanvas"><canvas>
  }
}
```

How can I init the canvas with some chart library like `chartjs` when it is loaded to dom ?

Comment: You may have a look at code from other guys who use Binding.scala with d3.js https://github.com/emanresusername/word-cloud-generator/blob/master/ui/src/main/scala/my/will/be/done/wordcloud/component/WordcloudComponent.scala

Comment: @YangBo I don't think that code resolve my issue.  Look at the example, if the `show` changes I need to redraw the chart. So I think it cloud be done  with binding.scala 's event listener.

Comment: Try put those redraw code in `if` block

Comment: @YangBo That probably not work, because the element was not loaded to dom when those code executes.

Comment: Then you need custom MountPoint

Comment: @YangBo Is there any example here ?

Comment: https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SingleMountPoint&type=

Comment: Is there some code you can point us to, where a custom MountPoint is used? I would be interested in a solution, too, but am not getting what to do from the code... Thanx!

Comment: @jens Finally I use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch element mounting.

Comment: @jilen: Thanx. Went with the MutationObserver, too. Works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1

```
@dom 
def chart(show: Var[Boolean]) = {
  if(show.bind) {
    val myCanvas = <canvas id="chartCanvas"><canvas>
    myInitializationCode(myCanvas)
    myCanvas
  } else {
    <!-- don't show canvas -->
  }
}
```

---

### Solution 2

You can create a custom [SingleMountPoint](https://static.javadoc.io/com.thoughtworks.binding/unidoc_2.11/11.0.0-M3/com/thoughtworks/binding/Binding$$SingleMountPoint.html), and put the initialization code in the overriden `mount` method:

```
val yourCustomMountPoint = new SingleMountPoint[Boolean](show) {
  override def mount() = {
    super.mount()
    // Your custom initialization code
  }
  override def unmount() = {
    // Your custom clean up code
    super.unmount()
  }
  override def set(newValue: Boolean) = {
    // Your custom handler when `show` get changed
  }
}

// Inject your custom mount point into the rendering process
yourCustomMountPoint.bind
```

Comment: Thank you. That added the missing part for me.