# binding.scala component to string conversion

Tags: scala.js, binding.scala

I have a binding.scala component and a third party scalajs library that takes html string as input. How can the b.s component can be passed to the library method as an argument?

Specifics:

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding._
import com.thoughtworks.binding.{Binding, dom}

@dom def renderComponent: Binding[Element] = <h1> I am a component </h1>

def thirdPartyFunction(str: String) = {
  ...
}
```

I would like to call the function like `thirdPartyFunction(renderComponent.bind.outerHtml.toString)`.
However that call never gets executed.

I think this is related to some basic understanding with B.S up until now I have not faced with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Missing `watch` calls?

Comment: the `thirdPartyFunction` is invoked by a window event. Not through `dom.render` method though. Something like this, but how: `window.onload = _ => thirdPartyFunction(renderComponent.bind.outerHtml.toString)`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to wrap the `.bind` call with `watch`. For instance, in the `window.onload` function, something similar to the following:

```
   window.onload = _ => Binding{
       thirdPartyFunction(renderComponent.bind.outerHtml.toString)
   }.watch()
```

Note that it is possible to initialize components without functions like `window.onload`. See this question [How to execute some init after element loaded to dom with Binding.scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917823/how-to-execute-some-init-after-element-loaded-to-dom-with-binding-scala/45101054#45101054)